# How do I view and publish packages from NuGet package explorer in an Azure DevOps private feed?

Tags: azure, nuget

The Azure DevOps documentation walks through how to access NuGet packages through Azure Artifacts credential provider and Visual Studio, but I can't find any information on connecting NuGet Package explorer and an Azure DevOps private feed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's a "Connect to feed" button that enables you to connect to the feed from different tools. Seems like [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer/issues/839) discusses what you're looking for.